# Backup Encryption Password

Tags: itunes, windows, restore, ios, encryption

My IPad 2 crashed recently and I was forced to upgrade to IOS8. However, when I try to restore my local backup it no longer recognises my password. What do I do to restore my data??? I'm running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/05/03/decrypting-the-iphone-keychain-from-backups/#comments
see my post (Dick) of September 22, 2015 at 5:56 pm how I succeeded.

Comment: The above link no longer goes to any single article.